# How to show different list of items when clicking on a category button? React/javascript

Tags: reactjs

How can I show while clicking on a category button, another list of products.
Because it shows now 1 productlist from a array in our back-end, but I want that it gonna switched to another list while I clicking on a button. I maybe has to do something with selection id..

[enter image description here][1]

```
function App() {

  const [productList, setProductList] = useState([]);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCategoryId, setSelectedCategoryId] = useState(0);

 const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

  function fetchCategoryHandler() {
     fetch('http://localhost:4567/categorie').then(response => {
       return response.json();
     }).then(data => {
       const transformedCategories = data.map(categoryData => {
         return {
          id: categoryData.CategorieNaam,
          name: categoryData.CategorieNaam,
          products: categoryData.products
         };
       });


       setCategories(transformedCategories);
       setProductList(transformedCategories[selectedCategoryId].products);
       console.log(transformedCategories[selectedCategoryId].products);
     });
  } 
  const [defaultPage, setDefaultPage] = useState([]);

  const showDefaultPage = () => {
    setDefaultPage(0);
  };

  const categoryChosen = (chosen) => {
    setDefaultPage(1);
  };


  const [activeComponent, setActiveComponent] = useState("CategoryList"); 

  

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCategoryHandler();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header countCartItems={cartItems.length}></Header>
      <div className="row">

        
//categorylist 
        <Categorielijst categories={categories}
                        setCategory={setSelectedCategoryId} 
                        activeComponent={activeComponent} 
                        setActiveComponent={setActiveComponent}
                        />

//productlist
        <Productenlijst listOfProducts={productList} 
                        onAdd={onAdd}
                        setActiveComponent={setActiveComponent} />



//orderlist its a other component
        <Bestellijst
          cartItems={cartItems}
          onAdd={onAdd}
          onRemove={onRemove}
        ></Bestellijst>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMRPB.png
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
const handleOnClickCategoryButton = () => {
  if(!categories.length) return;
  //gets a random id
  const newCategoryId = Math.floor(Math.random * (categories.length - 1));
  setProductList(categories[newCategoryId].products);
}
// ....
//Button
<button onClick={handleOnClickCategoryButton}>Change category</button>
```

Comment: I had add on my codes this:


const switchCategory = (chosenCategory) => {
setSelectedCategoryId(chosenCategory);
};